# Find duplicate values in 2 different columns in one table using SQLite

Tags: sqlite

```
EmpID   EmpName         LineManager      eMail
=========================================================
11111   Alex Sanchez    Robert Wham      alex@abc.com
22222   Willis Max      Nara Zee         willis@abc.com
33333   Robert Wham     Melissa Baker    robert@abc.com
44444   Nara Zee        Jane Stewart     nara@abc.com
```

In the example above, Robert Wham and Nara Zee are both line managers and employees.

I need a SQLite query to find such a case and retrieve the following:

1. EmpID
2. Duplicate Name AS Emp_Line
3. eMail of Emp_Line

Thanks for all....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a self join from employee to line manager:

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.EmpName = t2.LineManager
```

This would return each record for an employee who happens to also have an entry as a line manager.  If there could be more than one record for an employee, then you could use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead.  Note that your table is not very robust, in the sense that more than one employee or manager could have the same name.  Ideally you would store a unique employee ID of some kind and we could join on that instead.

Comment: I don't think you ran my query, but rather something else.  I only select columns from a single table, and hence that ambiguous column error should not be happening.  Can you try running my _exact_ query and then let me know what happens?

Comment: Thanks for your response... I got this Error: [12:02:07] Error while executing SQL query on database 'ReportGenerator': ambiguous column name: Staff.EmpID. I got this data from an Excel sheet as is and needed to find out the above explained. Please consider that the line manager can be so for many employees.

Comment: @Milad That is _NOT_ my query.  You are getting the error because you did not use aliases for the table, hence SQLite is seeing double.  Just run my query and all should work.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM Staff t1 INNER JOIN Staff t2 ON t1.EmpName = t2.LineManager`